# QuickBooks Enterprise bitcoin

Tags: accounting

My company is switching to QuickBooks enterprise. The only thing I would like to know before making the switch is if you can track bitcoin payments through the software.

Comment: While I doubt it, have you enquired to QuickBooks themselves?